# Aplicar fórmula linha a linha dentro de uma tabela no R

Tags: python, r, microsoft-excel

Tenho uma tabela onde preciso aplicar uma fórmula linha a linha para várias colunas, e a fórmula é:

valor da linha - média(todos os valores da coluna) / desvio padrão(todos os valores da coluna)

é uma normalização dos dados para aplicar no modelo de machine learning.

```
fx <- c(6.9, 6.8, 6.7, 6.0, 6.8)
```

O cálculo seria nesse caso:

6,9 - media(fx) / desvio_padrão(fx)...
6,8 - media(fx) / desvio_padrão(fx)...
6,7 - media(fx) / desvio_padrão(fx)...

Alguém teria alguma alternativa pra esse caso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `R` tem uma função específica para isso chamada `scale`:

```r
fx <- c(6.9, 6.8, 6.7, 6.0, 6.8)
fx_scale <- scale(fx)
fx_scale
#>            [,1]
#> [1,]  0.7129310
#> [2,]  0.4387268
#> [3,]  0.1645225
#> [4,] -1.7549072
#> [5,]  0.4387268
#> attr(,"scaled:center")
#> [1] 6.64
#> attr(,"scaled:scale")
#> [1] 0.3646917

as.vector(fx_scale)
#> [1]  0.7129310  0.4387268  0.1645225 -1.7549072  0.4387268
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Obrigado @Marcus Nunes, me ajudou muito, tentei aplicar em várias colunas do meu dataset, porém não funcionou, tentei usar a função round(apply(df[6:],2,scale)), pois quero pegar a coluna a partir da 6 até o final do dataset, sabe alguma maneira que poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Use `scale(df[, 6:ncol(df)])`